# WebApi Moq. Field in method under test not initialized

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I'm trying to test WebApi post method. But I'm completely confused with the reason why test failed - look like class constructor have not been initialized.
Here is method under test:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(TourObjectViewModel viewmodel)
{
    var answer = new ActionAnswer(); \\this variable is null
    try
    {
        var dto = new TourObjectDTO
        {
            TypeId = viewmodel.TypeId,
            Name = viewmodel.Name,
            Address = viewmodel.Address,
            Latitude = viewmodel.Latitude,
            Longitude = viewmodel.Longitude,
            CountryId = viewmodel.CountryId,
            RegionId = viewmodel.RegionId,
            CityId = viewmodel.CityId.Value,
            Rating = viewmodel.Rating,
            InternalRating = viewmodel.InternalRating,
            CheckInTime = viewmodel.CheckInTime,
            CheckOutTime = viewmodel.CheckOutTime,
            HowToGet = viewmodel.HowToGet,
            Web = viewmodel.Web,
            Email = viewmodel.Email
        };
        answer = await _tos.Add(dto);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat("Method:{0} <br/> Error: {1}", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
        return BadRequest(answer.ToString());              
    }
    return  Ok(answer.ToString());
}
```

And here is test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task AddTourObject()
{
    // Упорядочение
    var mockService = new Mock<ITourObjectService>(MockBehavior.Default);
    var dto = new TourObjectDTO()
    {
        TypeId = 10,
        Name = "fgasdfsdfasdf",
        Address = "fgasdfsdfasdf",
        Latitude = 120.22,
        Longitude = 220.34,
        CountryId = 1,
        RegionId = 2,
        CityId = 1,
        Rating = 2,
        InternalRating = 2,
        CheckInTime = "12:00",
        CheckOutTime = "12:00",
        HowToGet = "sss",
        Web = "web",
        Email = ""
    };
    var viewmodel = new TourObjectViewModel
    {
        TypeId = 10,
        Name = "fgasdfsdfasdf",
        Address = "fgasdfsdfasdf",
        Latitude = 120.22,
        Longitude = 220.34,
        CountryId = 1,
        RegionId = 2,
        CityId = 1,
        Rating = 2,
        InternalRating = 2,
        CheckInTime = "12:00",
        CheckOutTime = "12:00",
        HowToGet = "sss",
        Web = "web",
        Email = ""
    };
    mockService.Setup(x => x.Add(dto)).ReturnsAsync(new ActionAnswer { });
    var controller = new TourObjectController(mockService.Object);
    // Действие
    var result = await controller.Post(viewmodel);
    // Утверждение
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<ActionAnswer>));
}
```

Test failed with NRE:

> System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на
>   экземпляр объекта..
>           в Camps.Api.Controllers.TourObjectController.`<Post>`d__5.MoveNext() в
>   D:\Dev\Camps\Camps.Api\Controllers\TourObjectController.cs:строка 147

Comment: Post the error message on why the test failed.

Comment: @Nkosi, _tos is the service injected into controller, Add method signature is: public async Task<ActionAnswer> Add(TourObjectDTO dto)

Comment: @andrey.shedko I eventually figured that out after rereading your post. hence why i removed my comment. check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Add setup is expecting a specific object but you are constructing a new object in the method under test. if the goal is just to return the an `ActionAnswer` on add then try

```
mockService.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TourObjectDTO>())).ReturnsAsync(new ActionAnswer { });
```